# Convert back from int to byte

Tags: python, type-conversion, int, byte

How would I go about doing the inverse for the following; I converted bytes to integers but now I need to go back to the original byte value.

```
 bytevalues = int.from_bytes(bytevalues, byteorder='big')
```

Comment: Does the `bytes` builtin do what you want?

Comment: I get   OverflowError: int too big to convert    when using int.to_bytes(). Not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you add example input and expect output to your question?

Comment: give b'\xd4\x1fe\xf1\x85\xe6\x04\x12|\xfd\x8dw\x99/\x01\xd0' I'd like to convert to int which should be 281959363967813457943773814912663355856 and later on I want to go back to the original byte value.

Comment: `int` instances have a method `to_bytes` that takes in a length and the byteorder,

Comment: Yes I used that which gives me OverflowError: int too big to convert  Is there any other way to do the same?

Comment: What did you set the `length` parameter to when calling `to_bytes`? The example in my answer works as expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the `int` [`to_bytes` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes). Here is an example:

```
value = int.from_bytes(bytevalues, byteorder='big') 
new_bytevalues = value.to_bytes(length=len(bytevalues), byteorder='big') 
print(new_bytevalues == bytevalues) # prints True
```

In `to_bytes`, we have to define length to be at least the size of the original `bytes` object. If it is not, it will cause an `OverflowError`. It can be bigger than the length of the original `bytes` object, and in that case it will just pad the result with zeros.